# Magento2.2 error while install extension

Tags: php, magento2.2

I have tried to install `magento extension` in `magento 2.2` using `magento connect`. But during readiness check I am getting the following error screen.

[image: Error]

I have enabled `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1` line in `php.ini` file. It does not help me.

I tried with lot of searching but not get a good solution.